# Wave eqation on Half Line

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider the wave equation  and take Dirichlet boundary conditions:

$$v_{tt} - c^2v_{xx} = =0 \ \  \ \  \ \  ( 0 < x < \infty, \ \ -\infty < t < \infty) $$

$$ v(x,0) = \phi (x) , \ \ v_t(x,0) = \psi(x) \ \  \ \  \ \  for \ \ t = 0 $$

$$ v(0,t) = 0 \ \  \ \  \ \  for \ \ x = 0 $$

Convert the given problem into whole line by taking an odd extension of $\phi$ and $\psi$:

$$ \phi_{odd} = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \phi(x) & \quad \text{if x > 0}\\
    -\phi(-x) & \quad \text{if x <0}\\
     0 & \quad \text{if x =0}
  \end{array} \right.$$

and

$$ \psi_{odd} = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \psi(x) & \quad \text{if x > 0}\\
    -\psi(-x) & \quad \text{if x <0}\\
     0 & \quad \text{if x =0}
  \end{array} \right.$$

$$u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} = =0 \ \  \ \  \ \  ( -\infty < x < \infty, \ \ -\infty < t < \infty) $$

$$ u(x,0) = \phi_{odd} (x) , \ \ u_t(x,0) = \psi_{odd}(x) \ \  \ \  \ \  for \ \ t = 0 $$

$$ u(0,t) = 0 \ \  \ \  \ \  for \ \ x = 0 $$

We know that the solution of the wave equation on the whole line is

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} \{\phi_{odd}(x+ct) + \phi_{odd}(x-ct) \} + \frac{1}{2c} \int \limits_{x-ct}^{x+ct}  \psi_{odd}(y) dy.$$

I want to show that

$$v(x,t) =  \frac{1}{2} \{\phi(x+ct) - \phi(ct-x) \} + \frac{1}{2c} \int \limits_{ct-x}^{x+ct}  \psi(y) dy.$$

Please help me show that $\phi_{odd}(ct+x) = \phi(ct+x)$ and $\phi_{odd}(x-ct) = -\phi(ct-x)$.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this application of the method of rotations, we are looking at $\phi$ across the two intervals $x>c|t|$ and $0<x<c|t|$ which are the areas above and below the curve $x=t$ respectively in the first quadrant. The difference in formula is established by this. Note that in the region $x>c|t|$, everything is positive, hence $\phi_{\text{odd}}(ct+x)=\phi(ct+x)$. For the region $0<x<c|t|$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\phi_{\text{odd}}(x-ct)=\phi(-(ct-x))=-\phi(ct-x)
\end{equation*}
by the properties of odd functions. 
To get the formula for $v(x,t)$, replace $y$ with $-y$.